# Let $(X,Y)$ be an absolute continuous R.V. Find $XY \mid Y = y$ and show $XY$ and $Y$ are independent. Also $XY \sim e(1)$.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(X,Y)$ be an absolute continuous R.V with density $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = ye^{-y(x+1)}, \ x,y >0$.

I've shown that $Y \sim e(1)$ and $X \mid Y = y$ density $x \mapsto ye^{-yx}$.

**However I must find $XY \mid Y = y$ and show $XY$ and $Y$ are independent. Also $XY \sim e(1)$.**

I've a theorem saying: $X=h(Y,Z)$ then $X \mid Y=y \sim h(y,Z) \mid Y=y$, but I can't figure out how to apply it or whether it should be applied.

Also I've tried to calculate $$P(XY \le k)=(X \le \frac k Y) = \int^{\infty}_0 \int^{\frac k y}_0 ye^{-y(x+1)} \ dx \ dy = 1-e^{-k}$$

but this is not $e(1)$, so I've done an error ? How can I proceed ?

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you start by finding the joint distribution (density) of $(XY,Y)$ and then calculate the conditional density of $XY$ given $Y=y$?

Comment: How should I find this joint distribution ? How can I see $(XY,Y)$ are independent ?

Comment: Use the transformation theorem you've used in your previous question perhaps.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, but could it be proved using the rules (theorems) I've added to my question ? These simplifies the process tremendously, but I cannot apply them as they are applied in examples.

Comment: "but this is not e(1)" Whaaat? Please read again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the theorem you gave, let $XY = h(Y, Z)$ where $h(y,z) = yz$ and $Z = X$. Then $XY | Y = y \sim yX | Y = y$. Thus for $t > 0$

\begin{align}
P(XY < t | Y = y) &= P(Xy <t | Y = y ) \\
&=  P(X < \frac{t}{y}  | Y = y) \\
& = \int_{0}^{\frac{t}{y}} y e^{-yx}dx \\
& = 1 - e^{-t}
\end{align}

The cdf of $XY$ is not affected by the value of $Y$, thus they are independent. And $1-e^{-t}$ is exactly the cdf of $e(1)$

Comment: How do you get the integral in the second last equality ? We don't know $f_{X}(x)$.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen As you have shown, we know the density of $X$ conditionally on $Y=y$

Comment: Also I know $XY \sim e(1)$ and $Y \sim e(1)$ then $XY | Y = y \sim \frac {f_{XY}(k)} {f_Y(y)} = 1$ ? But shouldn't I get the same result ?

Comment: Yes $XY \sim e(1)$ and $Y \sim e(1)$, but then how to reach your conclusion? The density of $XY | Y = y$ is equal to the joint density of XY and Y divided by that of Y

Comment: Ahh you are right. I'm a bit confused, but thanks for showing how to apply the theorem that was causing me trouble.